# One of my keys activate the command key for no reason

Tags: mac, keyboard

I cannot use one of my keys (specifically the 0 key) because whenever I press it, it activates the command key without me even touching it. Please help, this happened randomly. I was on discord at the time if that helps, but now I can't even log in without having to hold enter so I can press the 0 key. Even if I change the command key to something else like the control button it presses that button instead.

Also, now the / key activates =.
Same with the esc key, it activates `.
F12 lowers the volume and activates the up arrow.
Left Arrow activates ; activates . The keyboard is wireless, and the mac is Mac OS Sierra.

edit : Now it just stopped doing it? the glitches have stopped. That's strange.

Answer (score 0):

What model Mac are you using, there has been some issues with the keyboards on some of the newer Macs.

you can use canned air to clean things out on these keyboards.

or if that doesn't work there is a replacement program:

https://www.apple.com/support/keyboard-service-program-for-macbook-and-macbook-pro/